# How to judge if a symmetric matrix can be factorized into two vectors?

Tags: matrices

How can we judge if this matrix can be written as the product of a column and a row vector? $A=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha &  a & \alpha\\
\beta &  b & \beta\\
\alpha &  a & \alpha\\\end{bmatrix}$

I try to solve for the system of equations but I do not get a unique solution. Does this mean that the matrix cannot be factorized as such?

Thanks,
Elnaz

Comment: If it is of rank $1$.

Comment: also, this is not what is called symmetric, although it does have a symmetry.

Comment: So, I conclude that this is not factorizable as such.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A = vw^T$, then looking at just the top $2 \times 2$ block gives us:

$v_1w_1 = \alpha$

$v_1w_2 = a$

$v_2w_1 = \beta$

$v_2w_2 = b$

From this, we get $\alpha b = v_1v_2w_1w_2 = \beta a$.

So, we must have $\alpha b = \beta a$, else $A$ cannot be written as $vw^T$.

It is not hard to see that this condition is sufficient.